# Keep AngularJS Material labels above the field

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I am trying to get the labels for a field to manually stay up above the field instead of dropping inside of it:

Basically, I have a color picker with a label on top of it with a switch next to it. For some reason, the label keeps falling when the switch is selected and it collides with both the switch and the color picker. How to I keep the label above the field? Essentially, I need the opposite of md-no-float.

Pictures as reference:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Generally CSS absolute position issues can cause this but to be sure please update your question with the CSS, HTML used.

Comment: You must use md-input-container with md-no-float attribute to disable floating labels.